# Find out whether SPI is enabled or not

Tags: spi, bash

I have a game that needs SPI. In the installation instructions, I noted that SPI has to be enabled via `raspi-config`.

Now, I'd like to check in a shell script whether the user has activated SPI or not. How can I query the SPI state?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use raspi-config non-interactively to get the SPI status:

```
sudo raspi-config nonint get_spi
```

Which returns 0 (enabled) or 1 (disabled)

Similarly, enable with:

```
sudo raspi-config nonint do_spi 0
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `sudo raspi-config nonint do_spi 1`?

Answer (score 1):

SPI does not have to be enabled by raspi-config.  It is just a convenient way of doing so on Raspbian.

Try something like the following to check if the kernel SPI device exists.

```
#!/bin/bash

if [[ -e /dev/spidev0.0 ]]
then echo "SPI exists"
else echo "no SPI"
fi
```

This isn't fool proof as you don't need to use the kernel driver to use SPI.